# How to have robot.txt file at www.mywebsite.com/robot.txt when i am using ReactJS library for the frontend?

Tags: reactjs, robots.txt

I have a SPA website made with ReactJS(version 16.7.0), I want Robot.txt and Sitemap to show at the root of the website, www.mywebsite.com/robot.txt.

Also, I am using www.mywebsite.com/[name] as a route in the react app.

One thing I know that only having robot.txt and sitemap files at public folder won't help. I am using nginx server(if that helps).

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's React or not if you're not using things that are specific to React like CRA. This is very specific to how Nginx is configured. If you put static file to public root, it's supposed to be accessible.

Comment: Hope I could downvote my own question, I was using a wrong file name 'robots.txt' and looking for 'robot.txt' thanks @estus for giving me the confidence.